# Background image and navigation bar to full screen on page load

Tags: html, css

In my attempts to learn some web development, I've been trying to mimic certain websites I come across on the web. Right now I'm trying to emulate something along the lines of this website: http://www.cassidoo.co/

My question is how are you able to force the background image and navigation bar to fit the screen no matter the screen size?

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main">
                <h1>Text holder</h1>
                <p>Another text holder</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="about">
                <a href="#a1" id="about">TEXT1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="resume">
                <a href="#r1" id="resume">TEX21</a>
            </div>
            <div class="projects">
                <a href="#p1" id="projects">TEXT3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.container p {
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.jumbotron {
    background-image:url('http://goo.gl/o9un96');
    height: 800px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.jumbotron .container {
    position: relative;
    top:100px;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 48px;  
     font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.jumbotron p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #efeff1;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 768px;
}
nav div {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 18%;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav div a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
nav div a:hover {
    color: red;
}
.main p {
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Feel free to give pointers or any other information that would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. In your CSS set the `body` and `html`'s margin to 0 as well as their height as 100%.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Also change your `jumbotron` class's height to `100%`.

### Edit Again

Add `margin-top: 0;` to your `h1`. Here's all your CSS that I edited.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://goo.gl/o9un96');
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #efeff1;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main">
                <h1>Text holder</h1>
                <p>Another text holder</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        

        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="about">
                    <a href="#a1" id="about">TEXT1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="resume">
                    <a href="#r1" id="resume">TEX21</a>
                </div>
                <div class="projects">
                    <a href="#p1" id="projects">TEXT3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question you'd like to have the navigation "stick" to the bottom of the page, and then be able to scroll past it... Is that right?

You'll need to change you html markup and enclose everything in the first "page" within a container. This container's height needs to be 100% of the viewport.

```
.jumbotron {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Then your navigation will need to be positioned at the bottom of this container.

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

Checkout this fiddle for an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NateW/3rr59bgg/

Answer (score 0):

The particular site you are pointing to achieves this effect using javascript. The navigation bar is set to be 50px tall in CSS all the time, and then javascript sets the height of the header (your .jumbotron) to full window height minus 50px (the height of the nav). Javascript recalculates this number everytime the browser window is resized.

**Imagine this HTML**

```
<body>

<div id="headerBackground">
  <h1>Content in header</h1>
</div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

</body>
```

**This CSS**

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#headerBackground {
  min-height: 150px;
  background: green
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #efeff1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;  
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

**And this JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
// The first three lines sets the height of the header when the page first load
siteHeight = $(window).height();
navHeight = $('nav').height(); 
$('#headerBackground').height(siteHeight-navHeight+'px');

// The rest of the code sets new height for the header every time the browser window is resized
$ (window).resize(function() {

  siteHeight = $(window).height();
  $('#headerBackground').height(siteHeight-navHeight+'px');

});
```

So, there is no height: 100%; involved here, just constant math. I have set it up for you in a codepen so you can see how it is done :)

http://codepen.io/andersedvardsen/pen/yyzjyq